# c++ new operator usage issue

Tags: c++, new-operator

I just accidentally write the code below. 
It is compiled using gcc 4.4.7 in linux environment.

```
int main ()
{
        new int;
        return 0;
}
```

I am surprised the compiler does not indicate any error or warning. Is the c++ standard mentioned about this? Is it still possible to prevent memory leak in this situation? Any advice is welcome.

Comment: There is no error or warning signaled because that is perfectly valid C++. And no, you can't do anything about that leak.

Comment: @Mat: you should make that an answer rather than a comment

Comment: The point is that there are legitimate memory leaks. A lot of big programs (e.g. GCC) allocate some heap data at initialization, and don't bother freeing it.

Comment: is it possible to deallocate that? and is there a reason to use that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one reason why you should try to avoid raw "new" as much as possible in new code.
std::make_shared and in c++14 std::make_unique are much safer as they will ensure that memory gets deleted properly by returning shared_ptr and unique_ptr objects that know when and how to delete the object. The intention is that raw new will mostly only be needed in low level code implementing data structures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with this. This is valid in c++.

Comment: Apart from the memory leak.

Comment: Not all "leaks" are problems, @john.

Comment: No but the OP specifically asked about the memory leak, so to simply say there is no problem with this ignores his question.

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid C++.  Why are you surprised that it compiled?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent memory leaks you should use shared_ptr instead of raw pointers:

```
#include <memory>
int main ()
{
        std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int);
        return 0;
}
```

Now the new allocated object is deleted at the end of the scope. And you do not have a memory leak in you code. For more details have a look at the dynamic memory management of C++11 [Dynamic Memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)

Comment: Unless you need shared ownership or unusual deletion, you should use the simpler `unique_ptr`, which has no more overhead than a plain pointer. And of course, if the object is strictly scoped like this, you shouldn't use `new` at all without a good reason.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented, a program can "legitimately" leak memory.

On most operating systems (notably Posix or Linux), the kernel will release all the memory used by a process after the process [exits](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html).

So if during its initialization, a program allocates some (heap) data -in limited quantity- and don't bother releasing it at all, it is a "legitimate" memory leak (and may real programs exhibit that behavior: e.g. the GCC compiler, or Firefox browser, or most X11 client libraries, etc...).

However, leaks which happen continuously during the normal operation of the program and which increase the memory consumption are frowned upon.

Also, I believe that it can be proven that static analysis of memory leaks is equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) so there is no way to always detect it at compile time: either you'll get some [false alarms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_alarm), or some leaks will stay undetected.

At runtime, you could use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to chase memory leaks.

Also, the liveness of some memory zone is a global property of the program. Read more about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and perhaps consider using [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/).